# HttpPost Method not posting

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have two forms. Each form is linked to its respective ActionMethod. First form posts to its respective ActionMethod successfully but second form instead of posting to its respective ActionMethod, is rather posting to First form ActionMethod. Generated HTML is:

```
    <div id="tabs-ViewBranch">
<h2>Districts</h2>    
<p>
    <a href="/cityDistrict/createDistrict">Create New</a>
</p>
<form action="/cityDistrict/deletedDistricts" method="post"><p>
    <select id="Status" name="Status" onchange="
            var form1 = document.forms[0];            
            form1.submit();"><option value="0">Show Active</option>
<option value="1">Show Deleted</option>
</select>
</p>
</form><table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            name
        </th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            Gujranwala
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="/cityDistrict/editDistrict/4">Edit</a> |
            <a href="/cityDistrict/deleteDistrict/4">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>    
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-AddBranch">
<h2>Cities</h2>    
<p>
    <a href="/cityDistrict/createCity">Create New</a>
</p>
<form action="/cityDistrict/deletedCities" method="post">    <p>
        <select id="Status" name="Status" onchange="
            var form = document.forms[0];
            form.submit();"><option value="0">Show Active</option>
<option value="1">Show Deleted</option>
</select>
    </p>
</form>    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                No cities exists.
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>    
    </div>
</div>
```

Everything runs fine except for the second form is not posting to `deletedCities` and is rather posting to `deletedDistricts`. Can someone please guide me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here

```
var form = document.forms[0];
```

Both the JavaScript events cause the first form in the document to be submitted, because they both say `forms[0]`. I'd just do this:

```
onchange="this.form.submit();"
```

`this` refers to the current element, and each form element has a `form` property that finds the form it belongs to without having to specify a global index.

Or even better, define the event handlers outside the HTML (hint: jQuery is popular for this)

Comment: Awesome explanation. Thanks mate. Its working like a charm.